# Getting a Google + count using pos.plusones.get not working using c#

Tags: c#, count, google-plus

I have been trying to find how to pull out the count information for Google+.  I have tried using the code here (slightly modified): http://johndyer.name/getting-counts-for-twitter-links-facebook-likesshares-and-google-1-plusones-in-c-or-php/.  But I keep getting the following error when I out put to screen:

```
Google says:[ { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid Value", "data": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "invalid", "message": "Invalid Value" } ] }, "id": "p" } ]
```

My simple test page code below.  Any ideas?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Google says:" + GetPlusOnes("http://www.google.com"));
}

string GetPlusOnes(string url)
{

    string googleApiUrl = "https://clients6.google.com/rpc"; //?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ";

    string postData = @"[{""method"":""pos.plusones.get"",""id"":""p"",""params"":{""nolog"":true,""id"":""" + url + @""",""source"":""widget"",""userId"":""@viewer"",""groupId"":""@self""},""jsonrpc"":""2.0"",""key"":""p"",""apiVersion"":""v1""}]";

    System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(googleApiUrl);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/json-rpc";
    request.ContentLength = postData.Length;

    System.IO.Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
    writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    writeStream.Close();

    System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    System.IO.Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    System.IO.StreamReader readStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    string jsonString = readStream.ReadToEnd();

    readStream.Close();
    responseStream.Close();
    response.Close();

    return jsonString;
    //var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(jsonString);
    //int count = Int32.Parse(json[0]["result"]["metadata"]["globalCounts"]["count"].ToString().Replace(".0", ""));

    //return count;
}
```

This is so simple to do with facebook and twitter, why couldn't google follow the same pattern? Why so complex?

Answer (score 1):

Just as a guess, I assume you need to comment out `key` with yours, in this line:

```
string googleApiUrl = "https://clients6.google.com/rpc"; //?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ";
```

so it becomes something like:

```
string googleApiUrl = "https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you need to register for it.  Go here: https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:352290279458:services

Comment: https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:352290279458:services does not exist anymore, according to the comments at http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/google_plus_one_button_seo_count_api/ one should use 'the developers key' AIzaSyCKSbrvQasunBoV16zDH9R33D88CeLr9gQ.